# When I read data from Realtime database it fetch just username and fetch imageurl as "null" however i have url in Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

When I read data from the Realtime Database it fetches just username and fetches imageurl as "null" however I have URL in the Realtime Database. Here is the code.

```
 root.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    String userName =dataSnapshot.getValue(PostModel.class).getUserName();
                    String imageUrl=dataSnapshot.getValue(PostModel.class).getImageUrl();
                    postModelArrayList.add(new PostModel(userName,imageUrl));
                    WallPostAdapter wallPostAdapter= new WallPostAdapter(WallPost.this,postModelArrayList);
                    postRecycler.setAdapter(wallPostAdapter);
                    wallPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

**PostModel**

```
String userName,ImageUrl;

public PostModel() {
}

public PostModel(String userName, String imageUrl) {
    this.userName = userName;
    ImageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return ImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    ImageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```

}
**Database Image**

[image: Here is my database Image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your `PostModel` class.

Comment: Done sir I add PostModel classs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting "null" for the imageUrl because the following getter:

```
public String getImageUrl() {
    return ImageUrl;
}
```

Is looking in the database for a property called `imageUrl`, which actually does **not** exist. The correct getter should be called:

```
public String getPostUrl() {
    return ImageUrl;
}
```

As your property is called `postUrl`.

P.S. Because you are using public getters and setters, you should make the properties in the class private.